# C# GeckoBrowser disable confirm message after refresh

Tags: c#, refresh, gecko

How can I disable this prompt after refreshing a page that was retrieved by a POST request:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geRUA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
window.location=window.location;
```

Instead of

```
location.reload();
```